# Recuperar datos de un formulario

Tags: php

quizas lo que estoy preguntando es algo muy obvio, pero como estoy en aprendizaje prefiero consultar. Cuando tengo un formulario con todos los datos completos y al enviar me envía un mensaje de error, los campos input me traen de vuelta el dato escrito para no volverlo a escribir, pero en los combobox no me sucede lo mismo, como hago para rescatar la opción seleccionada.

Tengo el siguiente código

```
<select name="categoria" id="categoria">
        <option value=""></option>
            <?php
                if($data!=null) {
                    foreach ($data->data as $key => $value) {
                        if($value->Id==$pdata['categoria']){  
                            echo '<option selected value="'.$value->Id .'">' . $value->Label . '</option>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<option  value="'.$value->Id .'">' . $value->Label . '</option>';
                        } 

                    }
                }else{
                    echo '<option value="">--</option>';
                }


            ?>
        </select>

<select name="subcat" id="subcat">
            <option value="">--</option>
        </select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#categoria').change(function (){ 
        getSubject($(this).val());
    });
    function getSubcat(valor){
        $.getJSON( "getSubcat.php", { sub: valor }, function( data ) {
            var items = [];
            $('#subcat').find('option').not(':first').remove();
            $.each( data['Subcat'], function( key, val ) {
                $('#subcat').append($('<option>', {
                    value: val.Subcat,
                    text : val.Subcat
                }));
            });
        });
    }
    <?php 
        if($pdata['categoria']!=""){
            echo "getSubcat(".$pdata['categoria'].");";
        }
    ?>
});
```

Por favor, si me pueden ayudar.
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que utilizas laravel por lo cual mas facil es que utilices la funcion `withInput`, para mas referencia te dejo el enlace de la documentacion [Aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests).
A continuacion te muestro una linea de ejemplo en el controlador:

```
$validator=Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'input' => 'required'
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                Flash::error('Debes subir un archivo de tipo imagen.')->important();
                return redirect(route('create_public'))->withInput();
            }
```

Comment: Gracias por la información

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres hacer es que te quede en la opción de **selected** una vez que envíes el **submit** aquí te dejo el ejemplo:

```
<select name="categoria" id="categoria">
        <option value=""></option>
            <?php
                if($data!=null) {
                    foreach ($data->data as $key => $value) {

                        if($value->Id == $_POST['categoria']){  
                        echo '<option selected value="'.$value->Id .'">' . $value->Label . '</option>';
                        }else{
                         echo '<option  value="'.$value->Id .'">' . $value->Label . '</option>';
                        }    

                    }
                }else{
                    echo '<option value="">--</option>';
                }


            ?>
        </select>
```

**Nota:** Estoy usando la variable global **$_POST** para capturar el valor seleccionado con con anterioridad. La estoy colocando en un **if**, en el cual estoy diciendo que si, el valor de **$value->Id** es igual al valor capturado en el formulario me lo muestre después del **submit**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, he implementado el if para rescatar el post, pero sigue devolviendo el select para vovler a seleccionarlo :(

Comment: Si puedes hacer el hacer un debug y comprueba que valor te esta devolviendo **$value->Id**  y **$_POST['categoria']**  deben de ser iguales para que el if trabaje. Una pregunta mas estas usando algún framework o lo estas haciendo todo con php desde cero.

Comment: Estoy realizando una comunicacion desde laravel, donde a través de json llamo a la funcin del combo box, edite mi código anterior. Gracias

Comment: No conozco **laravel** pero si no es **php** puro el **framework** debe tener un métodos o función en la cual captura los valores del formulario en lugar de usar el **$_POST** usa el método propio del **framework**  una cosa mas estas enviando los datos por **ajax** o desde el **submit** del **html**

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, en vez de usar el $_POST utilice $_SESSION['pdata'] y ahí si me tomó el select enviado en el submit

Comment: De nada, me alegra que te allá servido mi explicación. Gracias.

Comment: No se si me pudieras orientar con otra duda que tengo, el primer select corresponde a categorias y dependiendo de la categoría que yo seleccione, me arroja un nuevo combobox con la subcategoria.  Hasta ahí ningún problema por que me cargan las que corresponden a cada categoría, pero cuando recargo la página por error no me aparece el select de subcategoria con la opción seleccionada, sino que me llega para que vuelva a seleccionar, es posible contar con dicho dato una vez que el usuario recargue la página? Editaré el código y lo pondré los 2 select. Gracias

Comment: Aquí lo primero que hay que tomar en cuenta, es que eso lo tienes que hacer con **ajax** no se si con **lavarel** puedes usarlo pero pienso que si. Para ser eso tienes que hacer una función **javascript**  que te llene el **select** una vez que recargue la página, te recomiendo que guardes en valor seleccionado en el segundo **select** para que puedas usar la opción seleccionada esto es la una posible solución pueden existir otras.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias